# Appending and removing URL parameters based on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some filters that are being displayed as checkboxes on my website. Each time someone checks or unchecks one of these inputs I either want to add or remove the filter to/from the URL. I have this mostly working, but the problem comes when removing the last filter in the list.

Here's an example:

```js
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
        }
    }
};

$(function () {
    var colors = getUrlParameter('colors');
    var currentUrl = location.href;
    
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
      var inputVal = $(this).val();
      
      if (this.checked) {
        // Add filter to URL params
        colors = getUrlParameter('colors');
        if (!colors) {
          // No filters exist yet
          currentUrl += '?colors=' + inputVal;
        } else {
          // At least one filter exists
          currentUrl += ',' + inputVal;
        }
        console.log(currentUrl);
        window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", currentUrl);
      } else {
        // Remove filter from URL params
        currentUrl = currentUrl.replace(inputVal + ',', '');
        console.log(currentUrl);
        window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", currentUrl);
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="blue" />Blue</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="red" />Red</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="green" />Green</label>
</div>
```

This works if the color is first(if there or other filters) or in the middle of the list of filters, since it matches my `replace()`, wondering how I can do this dynamically so that it will remove both the color and the comma if necessary or remove the `colors=` altogether if none are checked.

For example, if all 3 colors are checked the url would look like this:

```
http://example.net?colors=blue,red,green
```

If you then remove `blue` it should look like this:

```
http://example.net?colors=red,green
```

If you then remove green it would look like this:

```
http://example.net?colors=red
```

And finally, removing red would look like this:

```
http://example.net
```

Comment: Here's a solution without manual parsing: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/416rfngb/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to split your colors into an array and then merge it back again at the end.

```
$(function () {
    var colors = getUrlParameter('colors');
    var currentUrl = location.href;

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
      var inputVal = $(this).val();
      var colorsQuery = getUrlParameter('colors') || "";
      //Split into an array after each `,`
      colors = colors.split(",");
      if (this.checked) {
        //Add to our current colors
        colors.push(inputVal);
      } else {
        // Remove from our current colors
        const index = colors.indexOf(inputValue);
        colors.splice(index, 1);
      }
      colorString = "";
      if(colors.length){
         //Merge back into a string with a `,`
         colorString = "?colors=" + colors.join(",")
      }
      window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", currentUrl + colorString);
    });
});
```

It's much easier to work with arrays in this instance so we just [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to convert to and from an string to array.

For adding its easy we can just push onto our array

To remove a color we find out where it is in our colors array. Then using [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) remove it from our array.

Comment: I voted up here, but the answer is very JS-ey and jQuery-ful. Our logic works out very similar, but for posterity it's there to be more vanilla-JS friendly and probably performant.

Answer (score 1):

I'd seperate adding and removing objects, and the logic to get your querystring.

You'll see here two basic events:

1. Update an object based on the current checkbox (Binding directly to the state is even better!)
2. Generating the string based off of current values.

```js
var colors = {
  'red': false,
  'blue': false,
  'green': false
};

update = function(color) {
  colors[color] = !colors[color];

}

getParams = function() {
  var setQuery = false;
  var expr = [];
  for (var color in colors) {
    if (colors[color]) {
      expr.push(color);
      setQuery = true;
    }
  }

  if (setQuery) {
    console.log("www.example.com" + "?colors=" + expr.join(","));
  } else {
    console.log("www.example.com");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onchange="update('red')" /> Red
<input type="checkbox" onchange="update('blue')" /> Blue
<input type="checkbox" onchange="update('green')" /> green

<button type="button" onclick="getParams()">Get params</button>
```